# jquerycsvtotable + tablesorter: hold the display untill everything is loaded?

Tags: tablesorter

I use tablesorter in combination with jquerycsvtotable.
Everything works fine, but... there's a lag between the moment when the table is loaded and the moment when tablesorter is shown that makes the data appear without any formatting on the screen. The time varies on the amount of data, between 2 and say 5 seconds.

Is there any way to show a "loading" gif or just nothing untill all the process is completed to avoid showing ugly data?

Thanks!

PS: I don't mean the time tablesorter takes to re-order rows when you click on a certain header cell, which I know is already arranged with optional processing gifs shown into the header...

EDIT: please find below my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/ts/css/theme.default.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ts/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ts/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/csv/js/jquery.csvToTable.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
  var mytable = $('#tabla1')
    .CSVToTable('/est/data/cli_30_0000.txt',{
      loadingImage: '/js/csv/images/loading.gif',
      separator: ";"
    })
    .bind("loadComplete",function(){
      var footer = mytable.find('tr:last');
      mytable
        .find('thead').after( footer.wrap('<tfoot/>').parent() ).end()
        .tablesorter({
          sortList: [[5,0]],
          widthFixed : true,
          widgets: ["zebra", "filter", "stickyHeaders"],
          widgetOptions: {filter_hideFilters : true}
        });
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<p>
<a href=../../>Home</a> <a href=../>30</a> <a href=./>0000</a><br>
2013-04-15 12:45:17
</p>

<div>
<table id="tabla1" class="tablesorter">
</div>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share some code? Specifically how are you initializing csvToTable and tablesorter?

Comment: @Mottie Code added. Juste FYI, the CSV is 2000 lines long, 12 columns (one of them containing links),

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the solution is as easy as just adding the "tablesorter" class name to the table. If you are using a theme other than default, that theme name should also be included:

```
  var mytable = $('#tabla1')
    .CSVToTable('/est/data/cli_30_0000.txt',{
      tableClass: 'tablesorter tablesorter-default', // adjust theme name here
      loadingImage: '/js/csv/images/loading.gif',
      separator: ";"
    })
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Well, I am afraid this is not working. In this table I use the default theme, so I just copy/pasted your code. Don't worry,  not a critical issue. Thanks.